# Create a table as combinations of ranges sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am attempting to create a table that has combinations of 3 ranges.

Range 1 and Range 2 are equal.

Range 3 is different and a different length.

For any given row the value in Column 1 cannot be equal to the value in Column 2.

e.g. for Range 1: [1-2], Range 2: [1-2], Range 3: [5-7]

the expected result would be:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 |
1    | 2    | 5    |
1    | 2    | 6    |
1    | 2    | 7    |
2    | 1    | 5    |
2    | 1    | 6    |
2    | 1    | 7    |
```

I'm using the python sqlite3 package so I can use ranges in python. Previously I have been constructing the table using a generator that iterates over the 3 nested ranges as follows:

```
def all_the_combos():
    for x in range(1,len(all_x)+1):
        for y in range(1,len(all_x)+1):
            if x == y:
                continue
            for z in range(min(all_z),max(all_z)+1):
            yield (x, y, z) 

cur.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION')
cur.executemany('INSERT into All_Combos (x, y, z) Values (?, ?, ?)', all_the_combos())
```

However, this is slow for large ranges and I expect there is some clever way to use joins that would provide better performance. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This has not much to do with SQL. My iterator would look like this btw `((x, y, z) for x, y, z in itertools.product([1, 2], [1, 2], [5, 6, 7]) if x != y)` and I do not think you can make this much faster.

Comment: thanks for the iterator, much tidier.

Answer (score 0):

how about below. you need pandas module. if you don't have pandas execute "pip install pandas" before run this code.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

# your sample data
col1 = range(1,3)
col2 = range(1,3)
col3 = range(5,8)

# product -> dataframe -> sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("/path/to/sqlite3.db")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    row for row in product(col1, col2, col3)
        if not row[0]==row[1]
)
df.to_sql("output_table_name", con)
```

Comment: Helpful to know about pandas SQLite functionality and the generator comprehension. Unfortunately, no improvement in performance.